# Check multiple elements with a single listener

Tags: java, list, button, javafx, observable

I'm trying to create an email client. This is the output when I open the program:
[image]

As you can see, the only button enabled is the **Reply-All** one. This is because I cannot forward or reply to an email not selected, but I can reply to all the emails in the list. Then, If I delete all the emails this is the output:
[image]

All the buttons are disabled (and this is correct). Now, if I change account by pressing **Cambia Account** a new list of email will be generated, but the **Reply-All** button will not get enabled. I guess that this is because the listener only check the status of the current mail and not if there is a list of them. How can I solve it?
[image]

This is the code which manage the part where I disable the buttons:

```
public void initModel(DataModel model) {
    if (this.model != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Model can only be initialized once");
    }
    this.model = model;
    model.currentEmailProperty().addListener((obs, oldEmail, newEmail) -> {
        if (oldEmail != null) {
            reply.setDisable(false);
            forward.setDisable(false);
            replyall.setDisable(true);
        }
        if (newEmail == null) {
            reply.setDisable(true);
            forward.setDisable(true);
            replyall.setDisable(true);
        } else {
            reply.setDisable(false);
            forward.setDisable(false);
            replyall.setDisable(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `if` in the listener? The property values are overwritten in the second `if` for all execution paths.

Comment: The first if is to manage when I have a list of emails but no one is selected.

Comment: model the enable/disable state in your dataModel and then bind to the view state. Anyway, Ppease provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the disabled status of your `replyall` button depends on whether the list has items, why are you changing it in `currentEmailProperty` listener? You should listen to changes to the list and update it there.

Comment: I can't do it because I can't control the list from my Button Controller

Comment: You should do some research on how to communicate between controllers in JavaFX